# Compartir archivos entre proyectos que están en la misma solución asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto asp.net c#.
La solución tiene 2 proyectos ( proyecto A y proyecto B).

Proyecto A es la web para administradores y es donde ellos suben archivos css,los css que suben se guardan en una carpeta dentro del mismo proyecto A llamada "FileCss".

Proyecto B es la web para usuarios y es acá donde tengo el problema, debido a que los usuarios utilizan estos archivos css, por lo tanto lo que necesito es acceder desde el proyecto B a los "FileCss" que se encuentran en el Proyecto A.

Otro punto importante es que los archivos a los cuales voy a acceder desde el proyecto B deben actualizarse constantemente, ya que puede ocurrir que un administrador sube un nuevo css y ese css debe estar disponible inmediatamente para todos los usuarios, ya que una de las funcionalidades de la aplicación es que los usuarios puedan descargar estos archivos css.

Alguna suguerencia o ayuda de como solucionar este problema???

Saludos y agradezco a todos por su ayuda. =)

[Edición 1]

Creo haber avanzado un poco en la solución, sin embargo aun me falta algo...
Para compartir los elementos entre el proyecto "A" y el proyecto "B" agregue el siguiente código al csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
 <Content Include="..\Proyecto_A\File\*.css">
  <Link>File\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
 </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Los archivos se comparten correctamente pero sólo se comparten los archivos que existian al momento de compilar, los archivos que se agregan mientras la aplicación esta corriendo no son compartidos.
¿Como puedo solucionar esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualmente no es posible que se "refresque" automaticamente cuando cambias (agregas, borras o editas) algun archivo. Si es posible pero tendrias que hacerlo de manualmente. Como? Tienes que descargar el proyecto (Unload Project) y volver a cargarlo en la solucion para que las referencias se vuelvan a actualizar.

Aca te dejo un link de referencia: http://jamesrpatterson.com/blog/automatic-include-in-project-for-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Si todos tienen acceso web una alternativa puede ser que la carpeta compartida esté en modo de lista de directorio y que todos los que tienen que acceder tengan su clave de acceso para que no todo el mundo pueda hacerlo. Los archivos pueden descargarse inmediatamente. Para la actualización y modificación de los mismos se podría hacer desde la misma aplicación.
Estoy asumiendo que la aplicación está alojada en algún servidor local o remoto. Saludos.